# Pandas: Printing the Names and Values in a Series

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, pandas

When I use :

```
w = y.groupby['A'].size()
```

It gives me the column values of Column A and then the size of the grouping beside it.
Using w ( a Series ), how do I print separately the names of the groupings ?
The values of the grouping can be gotten via :

```
for i in w :
    print(i)
```

But I can't figure out how to get the names.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can iterate over series using `iteritems()`

```
In [100]: for index, val in w.iteritems():
   .....:     print index, val
   .....:
```

where, `index` has column names, and `val` value/size

Answer (score 5):

The [`index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/dsintro.html) member of a series is the "names", so:

```
for name, val in w.index:
    print name
```

will iterate over the names. For both, you can use

```
import itertools

for name, val in itertools.izip(w.index, w):
    print name, val
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'izip'

Comment: Depends on your Python version, this might be ``zip``.

Answer (score 2):

In python 3 the following works fine:

```
In [31]:
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":["a","b","c","a"]})
w = df.groupby('A').size()
w

Out[31]:
A
a    2
b    1
c    1
dtype: int64

In [61]:
for i,r in w.items():
    print(i,r)
​
a 2
b 1
c 1
```

As does `iterkv`:

```
In [62]:
for i,r in w.iterkv():
    print(i,r)
a 2
b 1
c 1
```

However, the portable method (will work in python 2 also) is to use [`iteritems`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iteritems.html#pandas.Series.iteritems)